# Triangular/geometric rainbow spiral

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, spiral

I've been trying to find out how to make a rainbow triangular spiral using Python.  I can make a square spiral but it won't import the color. Also it's not using triangles.

What the output is supposed to look like:

[image]

What I achieved:

[image]

My code:

```
    import turtle 
    import colorsys

    p = turtle.Pen()
    p.reset()
    p.down()
    p.speed(22)


    for i in range(100):
        p.forward(i)
        p.left(22222)

    dog = 0

    for i in range(100):
        color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(dog,1,1)
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        dog += 0.01
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not show your code as a graphic--show it as text in your question. That allows us to copy-and-paste your code to test it ourselves. It also allows others later to find your question by a web search.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review your code:

```
p = turtle.Pen()
p.reset()
```

What's the `reset()` for?  Nothing's been *set* yet so why *reset*?  Don't add code that doesn't further your goal.  Again here:

```
p.down()
```

The pen starts out down, so no need to change it.  In this command:

```
p.speed(22)
```

Where did `22` come from?  The documentation for `speed()` says it's argument is 1 ('slowest') through 10 ('fast') with 0 meaning 'fastest'.  It turns 22 into some other value -- if you don't know what, then don't use it!  For clarity, you should use the symbolic alternatives like 'slow'.

```
    p.left(22222)
```

Where did `22222` come from?  Why are you surprised you don't get a triangle?  For a perfect equilateral triangle we'd use 120 degrees, but we don't want a perfect one, we want a spiral, so we'll add a degree or two to that value.  Why this variable name:

```
dog = 0
```

Variable names should clarify what we're doing, not obscure it.  This variable is going to be cycling through the 'H' component of an 'HSV' color value where 'H' stands for 'hue'.  So let's use that.

Finally, we need a single loop, not two, so that drawing and color changes are happening at the same time:

```
from turtle import Screen, Pen
import colorsys

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Rainbow Spiral")

pen = Pen()
pen.speed('fastest')

hue = 0.0  # range is 0.0 to 1.0

for i in range(200):
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)  # pen wants RGB
    pen.pencolor(color)
    pen.forward(i * 2)  # double size
    pen.right(121)  # 120 degrees is an equilateral triangle
    hue += 0.005  # increment by 1/200

pen.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that I changed `left()` to `right()` to match your example spiral.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Programs tell a story.  Choose your character names (variables) carefully and avoid including elements (code) in the story that have no affect on its outcome.